# BOOTSTRAP Table in a PHP Foreach loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, foreach

I have som trouble finding out what i am doing wrong.
I am using Bootstrap Table in a foreach loop

```
 Foreach($fetchSite as $rows)
  {
      $sname = $rows['name'];
      echo "<div class='well'>"
      . "<h4>$sname</h4>";


      foreach ($fetchDep as $rowd)
      {  
          $depn = $rowd['dep'];
          echo "<h5>$depn:</h5>";

  foreach($fetchUserdata as $row)
  {
      $uname = $row['username'];
      $team = $row['team'];
      $stime = $row['sttime'];
      $depna = $row['dep'];
      $siten = $row['name'];

      if($sname == $siten)
      {




        if($depn == $depna)
        {
             echo "<div class='row'>"

        . "<div class='table-responsive'>"
        . "<table class = 'table table-striped' style='width: 500px;'>"
        . "<thead><tr><th>Bruger:</th><th>Team:</th><th>startet:</th></tr></thead>"; 

          echo "<tr><td>".$uname."</td><td>".$team."</td><td>".$stime."</td></tr>";
            echo "<tbody>"
        . "</tbody>"
        . "</table>"
        . "</div>"


        . "</div>";  
        }


      }


  }//end Foreach FetchUSerdata

  }// end Foreach Depfetch  
  echo "</div>";

  } // End Foreach FetchSite
```

[image: Foreach Loop]

The problem is that there are to many 
Bruger:, Team: and startet

i only want 1 line of Bruger, Team: and startet and then the users listed below.
I know where the problem is:

```
 if($depn == $depna)
        {
             echo "<div class='row'>"

        . "<div class='table-responsive'>"
        . "<table class = 'table table-striped' style='width: 500px;'>"
        . "<thead><tr><th>Bruger:</th><th>Team:</th><th>startet:</th></tr></thead>"; 

          echo "<tr><td>".$uname."</td><td>".$team."</td><td>".$stime."</td></tr>";
            echo "<tbody>"
        . "</tbody>"
        . "</table>"
        . "</div>"


        . "</div>";  
        }
```

But i dont no how to solve it.
Sorry for my bad english and stupid question. 
Merry Christmas

Comment: put table tag and th tags out of your loop  and it will be clear

Comment: Thanks M8! It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Foreach($fetchSite as $rows)
{
  $sname = $rows['name'];
  echo "<div class='well'>"
  . "<h4>$sname</h4>";


  foreach ($fetchDep as $rowd)
  {  
      $depn = $rowd['dep'];
      echo "<h5>$depn:</h5>";
     echo "<div class='row'>"
    . "<div class='table-responsive'>"
    . "<table class = 'table table-striped' style='width: 500px;'>"
    . "<thead><tr><th>Bruger:</th><th>Team:</th><th>startet:</th></tr></thead>"; 

 echo "<tbody>";
foreach($fetchUserdata as $row)
{
  $uname = $row['username'];
  $team = $row['team'];
  $stime = $row['sttime'];
  $depna = $row['dep'];
  $siten = $row['name'];

  if($sname == $siten)
  {
    if($depn == $depna)
    {
      echo "<tr><td>".$uname."</td><td>".$team."</td><td>".$stime."</td></tr>"; 
    }
  }
}//end Foreach FetchUSerdata
    echo "</tbody>"
    . "</table>"
    . "</div>"
    . "</div>";
}// end Foreach Depfetch  
  echo "</div>";

} // End Foreach FetchSite
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you would want to leave inside the foreach is the `<tr>` and `<td>` sections. Leave the `<table..>` and `<th>` (table headers outside) the foreach that way it will generate a table.

Example

```
echo "<div class='row'>"
     . "<div class='table-responsive'>"
     . "<table class = 'table table-striped' style='width: 500px;'>"
     . "<thead><tr><th>Bruger:</th><th>Team:</th><th>startet:</th></tr></thead>";

foreach($fetchUserdata as $row)
  {
      $uname = $row['username'];
      $team = $row['team'];
      $stime = $row['sttime'];
      $depna = $row['dep'];
      $siten = $row['name'];

      if($sname == $siten)
      { 
        if($depn == $depna)
        {   
          echo "<tbody>"
               ."<tr><td>".$uname."</td><td>".$team."</td><td>".$stime."</td></tr>";
               . "</tbody>"
        }
      }
  }
          echo "</table>"
               . "</div>"
               . "</div>";  
//end Foreach FetchUSerdata
```

Comment: @MrLister Thank you for the edit! I'm quite new to answering :)

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to understand what you're asking, but I think I got the gist. The following code example takes an array

```
$fetchSite = [
    [
        'something' => 'a',
        'something_else' => 'b'
    ],
    ...
]
```

and turns it into a table

```
something | something_else
----------+---------------
    a     |        b
```

code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach(array_keys($fetchSite[0]) as $column) { ?>
                <th><?=$column?></th>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($fetchSite as $row) { 
            foreach($row as $column) { ?>
                <td><?=$column?></td>
        <?php } 
        } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

perhaps that will help you

Comment: he just need to make the th not appear at every row it fetch.

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou ah I see